# Run console application from other console app

Tags: c#, console-application

I have a C# console application (A). I want to execute other console app (B) from within app A (in synchronous manner) in such way that B uses the same command window. When B exists, A should be able to read B's exit code.

How to do that? I need only this little tip on how to run this other app in same cmd window.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You can use [`Process.Start`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.start.aspx) to start the other console application.

You will need to construct the process with [`ProcessStartInfo.RedirectOutput`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.redirectstandardoutput.aspx) set to `true` and [`UseShellExecute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.useshellexecute.aspx) set to `false` in order to be able to utilize the output yourself.

You can then read the output using [`StandardOutput.ReadToEnd`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.standardoutput.aspx) on the process.

Comment: On Windows 10 where cmd is the Windows Server 2008 Build Environment, this does no longer work, the new application immediately opens a new window.

Answer (score 9):

You can start another process using the `Process.Start()` call. The [examples here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.standarderror.aspx) show how to read output from other process and wait for it to finish.

Answer (score 8):

I was able to run the program 'B' as part of the same command window by calling the following configuration:

```
ConsoleColor color = Console.ForegroundColor;
ProcessStartInfo startinfo = new ProcessStartInfo(nameProgramB);
startinfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
startinfo.UseShellExecute = false;
Process p = Process.Start(startinfo);
p.WaitForExit();
Console.ForegroundColor = color;
```

this way, both programs run seamlesly like they were one single program. 'nameProgramB' is the name to program 'B'. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you very much Chesare, it works fantastic. BTW, it seems that we don't need to set `.CreateNoWindow` to false, since it's already false by default. The critical property to set here, is `.UseShellExecute`, since its default is true, and it must be false for the second program to run in the existing window and not in a new one.

Answer (score 4):

You can start another process with Process.Start - doesn't really matter if it's a console app or not. If your app is already running in a console window the newly spawned app will use that console window as well.

```
var proc = Process.Start( "...path to second app" );
proc.WaitForExit();
var exitCode = proc.ExitCode;
```

Be sure to ready the docs on the Process class as there are a variety of little nuances that may affect the way your secondary app is launched.

Comment: Hi Paul. Altho 10 years passed since this answer, I checked it now, and `Process.Start("other_console_program")` creates a new (second) Console window. The only way to make it not create a second one, is to set create a ProcessStartInfo object, and then set its .UseShellExecute property to false. Like in Chesare's answer.

Answer (score 2):

you can "wrap" the old console app with the new one by including it in your references and starting it off by calling whatever method is called in the run method of the program class

Answer (score 1):

Fill out a [System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.aspx) 
and pass it to [Process.Start](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.start.aspx)

You can `WaitForExit` on the resulting process, and use then use `ExitCode` property of the process to see the return value.