# Run program B from program A only?

Tags: c#

I have a program named A, which is responsible for telling the user about the news and updates of my program, then it should run program B which is the main program. How would I make program B openable only from program A??

Comment: Without more details (and some code..) this is fairly broad.

Comment: @DangerZone This was pretty clear to me. He wants to make a launcher, like the one from the Blizzard games.

Comment: @ThalesPereira - Ok, so not unclear. But it is broad. Answerable of course, but answers would be equally broad.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Run console application from other console app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2366168/run-console-application-from-other-console-app)

Comment: @DangerZone Eh, that's not how I see it. It's pretty clear what he wants to do, at least to me. It's just a launcher. Making an App to open only when called by some other app is pretty specific to me.

Comment: @MattRowland This is not a console application, nor it is launched from a console app. This a question about a launcher, like those that are super common on the gaming industry - NCSoft, Blizzard, etc.

Comment: @ThalesPereira How did you get that from this question? The question asks how to run program B from program A with no other details.

Comment: @MattRowland It tells the user about updates in the application. To me, it seems like he want to simulate the behavior you see on the gaming industry in general. It does have other details!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't guarantee this to be the best solution, but it can be implemented pretty easily: try setting an environment variable for the program you're starting. When the new program starts up, it should check for that environment variable and shut down if it isn't present.

So in Program A:

```
public static void StartProgramB()
{
    Process p = new Process();
    p.StartInfo.FileName = "programb.exe";
    //Other startinfo calls go here: parameters, start options, etc.
    p.StartInfo.EnvironmentVariables["CalledFromProgramA"] = "true";
    p.Start();

    p.WaitForExit();
}
```

and in Program B:

```
public static void Main()
{
   if(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("CalledFromProgramA") != "true")
       return;
}
```

Comment: I apparently answered an unanswerable question... Didn't think it was too unclear